# What does “get down with the kids” or “be down with the kids” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> - To show how “down with the kids” she was.
> - He sounds like someone’s dad trying to “get down with” the kids.

Can somebody tell me what “down with” means in these sentences?

Answer (score 2):

*[Get down with the kids](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2042190/Why-getting-kids-like-cringeworthy.html)* normally mean speaking the children's language and be less like a adult with the kids.

But it can also mean enjoying yourself without restraint with the kids, as suggested by [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-down?showCookiePolicy=true):

> **get down**
>
> informal (mainly US) to enjoy oneself uninhibitedly, esp by dancing
>
> (with friends in a social setting) get down and party!

Comment: I use l33t speak on teh interwebz so I'm down with the kids, yo!